# Get the value from Request.QueryString into another method

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, request

I am trying to get the value of nom into StudentListByFilter(), can anyone help me with these? The default value is returned as 0. I want to insert the query string(nom) into the StudentAttendanceList() but the value is 0.

```
public partial class AttedanceManagementJT : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int nom = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ActivityId"]);
    }
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static object StudentListByFilter()
    {
        return ApplyMethods.StudentAttendanceList(Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ActivityId"]));
    }
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ActivityId"])So is this method really usable in StudentListByFilter()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't "pass" the value to this other method is that it isn't another method. It's a "Page Method", which operates in a separate request. In that second request, there is no "ActivityId" query string parameter.

However, you can pass the query string parameter from the first request, through Session state, to the second request:

```
public partial class AttedanceManagementJT : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int nom = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ActivityId"]);
        Session["nom"] = nom;
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static object StudentListByFilter()
    {
        return ApplyMethods.StudentAttendanceList(
            Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["nom"]));
    }
}
```

Comment: (y) The answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the page is called with or without some parameters and the session will hold the value from the previous call - that will cause issues. 
I found that the more stable solution in my case was to have some hidden field on the page, save the parameter to it on pageload, and then pass this value from client javascript to the webmethod as an additional parameter.